# Average lifespan of COM-12986 Addressable LEDs?

Tags: led

I am working on a project where I need to ensure that LEDs will work for at least 5 years (powered 24 hours/day). I need LEDs to be addressable like [COM-12986](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LED/COM-12877.pdf). Would this be a good choice (the LEDs don't need to be RGB they can be red (620nm in wave length))? What is the average lifespan of [COM-12986](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LED/COM-12877.pdf) LEDs?

I've read on [Electronics Weekly](http://www.electronicsweekly.com/blogs/led-luminaries/led-life-expectancy-2009-02/) that in average an LED can last for up to 50,000 hours, is this correct?

Could I increase the lifespan of an LED by using PWM at 50% duty cycle?

Comment: Tell us what the data sheet says to save us all having to research it.

Comment: The only data sheet I could find on COM-12986 is already included in the question.

Comment: Thats not a datasheet, that is a joke... "RGB lamp", yeah...

Comment: I know its a joke, I just can't find anything else... :(

Comment: They are apa-106 based leds. For quality leds 50k hours at 20mA is true. For unknown quality leds, who knows. You get what you pay for.

Comment: A major thing that affects LED (and semiconductor in general) lifetimes is temperature. I am guessing that there must be linear regulation built into these devices (as the supply voltage is higher than diode Vf), and this will add to the die temperature and have some negative affect on the LED, but it is not possible to say how much. I would be inclined to pick a device with a better data sheet and one which the manufacturer is prepared to quote lifetimes for.

Comment: As some empirical evidence, I have a cheap led Christmas light that has been plugged in for a solid three years. Out of 100 bulbs two seem to have died. I also bought some random blue leds for my car. Out of 20, six or eight have died. One set was better quality and I think those haven't died. The ones that did seem to be the cheaper ones that over drove the leds to 35 milliamps. They started blinking and finally went out. And the leds only got used maybe 1 hour a day, 5 days a week. You get what you pay for.

Comment: @user1582568 Could you refer me to such manufacturer?

Comment: @ErikKralj sorry, I am not familiar with addressable LEDs applications in detail.

Comment: @user1582568 Could I accomplish higher lifespan using PWM with 50% duty cycle (I am not concerned with brightness that much) or would that shutdown the micro controller inside?

Comment: I think just setting the devices to a lower output would have the same effect as I am guessing that they use PWM control internally to regulate brightness.

Comment: Best lifetime for a given brightness would probably be obtained by using a voltage which yields the desired brightness at 100% duty cycle.  Using a higher voltage and reduced duty cycle will increase heating.  Not as much as it would if the duty cycle were held at 100%, but if brightness is constant, higher voltages will be more heat.

Comment: I have found this application note from a reputable company (Optek). http://optekinc.com/pdf/App%20Bulletin%20228.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the lifetime of an LED ask the manufacturer if its not listed in the datasheet. In the past I've also looked for LED's with simmilar specs to get a ball park estimate. These are usually MTBF ratings. that means some will fail early and some will last a lot longer. Usually part degradation is due to heating so any way to minimize heating will help (either by reducing the power or some other means.) I think 100k hours is what we used for the lifetime on our LEDS in our products so we turned them off when we wern't using them. But have you ever had a VCR or other product with a burned out LED, I never have noticed any, but most of them are low power.